# How do I make a tentacle that can hugs walls and slither on the ground?

Tags: animation

What would be a quick and easy approach for a system that will prevent a tentacle to not go through the floors or walls?

[image]

Comment: What about collisions?

Comment: Does quick and easy apply in the brief desciption?

Comment: BentleyCarpenter@ Collision for the wall and the same collision for the tentacle doesn't work at all.

Comment: I tried rigid body for both and passive & animated checked for the tentacle, no effect.

Comment: The words 'quick' and 'easy' rarely apply in animation, but you may want to take a look at [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/lBXFJA6UdaI) for an idea of how to make a tentacle rig that has most of the properties you want.  Be warned that it's a fairly advanced rig.

Comment: If you want to use rigid body physics with the armature I would look for a rag doll setup. No idea if this works with tentacles. Otherwise, cloth with internal springs could be an option. It depends on how much control you want...  https://imgur.com/a/BKc4TMY

Comment: @Blunder I want exactly what you have shown. Can you provide your blend as part of the answer please. I know cloth but the what is the internal springs you talk about?

Comment: @Blunder OK I get it now, I didn't realize it was one of the cloth settings.

Comment: Yes, it's a setting of the cloth physics.